# IP command using to 100% CPU on wakeup

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, cpu-load, wakeup

On laptop wakeup I see a process called `ip` that uses 100% CPU. It won't stop on its own, I need to manually kill it every time.
By looking for it in `ps` I could find that the command being run is `ip route show`.
When I run it manually, the command also doesn't terminate and prints the same few lines over and over again:

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp59s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.2.0.0/16 via 255.255.255.255 dev tun0 
10.251.0.0/16 via 255.255.255.255 dev tun0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp59s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-c2ea5a493560 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-51f86a6b837f proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp59s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.92 metric 600 
255.255.255.255 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.251.1.3 
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp59s0 proto dhcp metric 600
```

EDIT: the issue seems to disappear when I turn off my vpn

Ubuntu 19.10, Dell XPS-15-9570, kernel 5.3.0-41

This is really affecting my battery life. Anyone has experienced a similar issue or know how to fix it?

Comment: show us the lines that repeat over and over again.

Comment: edited the question to include the lines

Comment: Dd you try to figure out what its parent is (must be called from some script). You may discover that this is a script that is run on wakeup... Also what is this `tun0` device? Are you using a VPN?

Comment: I can't see what's calling this command, but the tun0 is a vpn (managed by openvpn).
When I turn it off, `ip route show` terminates immediately, and the issue is gone.

Comment: And which VPN is that? I mean did you manually configure it? Or it's a third party software like NordVPN, etc.

Comment: That sounds like a VPN script gone rouge

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar issue with my VPN what I did is reset the network configuration, sometimes they just get messed up, don't ask me idk why, try this link here:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restart-network-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Answer (score 0):

Try to simple use a different kernel version.

I'm telling this because could be related to a kennel VPN related regression.

If possible use an older kernel.